# Cannot use roo with attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Im quite a begginer on ruby ; I ve been trying to use roo and still cannot import anything ! after hours of search, I guess problem comes from new rails version which doensn't use accessible_attributes anymore (tutorials are well done, but they all use this command...)
there is no

here is the model code i am trying to fix.

```
 #attr_accessible :name, :price, :released_on
  #validates_presence_of :price    

def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
case File.extname(file.original_filename)
when '.csv' then Roo::Csv.new(file.path)
when '.xls' then Roo::Excel.new(file.path)
when '.xlsx' then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path)
else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
end

def self.import(file)
spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
header = spreadsheet.row(1)
(2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
  row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
  product = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
  product.attributes = row.to_hash.slice #(*accessible_attributes)
  product.save!
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
  row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
  product = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
  product.attributes = row.to_hash
  product.save!
end
```

And make sure you've set correct permissions in your controller like that:

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price, :released_on)
end
```